# Detectar quebra de linha antes de acontecer

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
ul{
  listy-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.an{
   width: 300px;
 }

ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  color: #f0f;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f;
  transition: .2s;
  border-radius: 5%;
  width: 10%;
}

ul li:hover{
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #ff00ff -4%, #3366cc 28%);
  color: #00ff00;
  padding: 10px 16px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Jquery</li>
  <li>HTML 5</li>
  <li>JavaScript</li>
  <li>CSS 3</li>
  <li>PHP</li>
  <li>C#</li>
</ul>
<br ><br ><br >
<ul class='an'>
  <li>Jquery</li>
  <li>HTML 5</li>
  <li>JavaScript</li>
  <li>CSS 3</li>
  <li>PHP</li>
  <li>C#</li>
</ul>
```

Pessoal olhem só estes 2 menus, o primeiro funciona banaca tudo certo e ok!

Porém quando limitamos o espaço que ele ocupa seja definindo uma width especifica menor que o necessário ou quando redimensionamos a tela, acontece essa 'quebra de linha'.

Existe alguma forma de conseguir detectar esta quebra de linha antes mesmo que ela aconteça?

Por Exemplo: Se eu estiver redimensionando a tela e a quebra de linha for acontecer eu consiga chamar uma função que irá resolver o problema.

OBS: É possível fazer isso definindo @medias(CSS) ou pelo innerWidth(JS) porém eu preciso saber a posição exata em que ele irá quebrar e colocar no código. Se fosse possível, gostaria de conseguir fazer isso sem conhecer o ponto onde ele quebra.

Comment: Cara essa parte de layout normalmente é feito no css com "media queries". Eu desconheço qualquer evento que identifique que vai haver quebra de linha no seu layout. E mesmo que existisse você estaria fazendo isso de uma forma ruim! O melhor seria travar o seu menu para não quebrar ou ter uma versão de layout dele para telas menores!

Comment: Sim Sim, já faço os menus ou outros elementos com as @medias, e o menu também se adapta a tela menores facilmente. O problema é que o meu menu é dinâmico, e a quantidade de itens presentes dependerá do usuário. Assim fica difícil definir uma quebra eficiente, ja que o menu pode ter de 1 a inúmeros itens.

Comment: Nesse caso esse tipo de menu não parece ser o mais adequado. Mas caso você queira detectar a quebra de linha. Você pode dar um tamanho fixo para seus <li> com isso, quando a página carregar basta você pegar o tamanho da página e verificar se o número de <li> ultrapassa esse tamanho. Mas eu evitaria usar um menu dessa forma. Porque vai que o usuário cadastra 50 itens. Quebraria completamente o seu layout!

Comment: O problema é que você está definindo a ul com tamanho fixo em px e as li com tamanho variável em porcentagem. O quê você pode fazer é definir a li com um max-width levando em consideração a maior palavra e deixar sem declarar a width.

Comment: Alan essa estrutura que montei foi apenas para mostrar qual é o problema que acontece. Gostaria que fosse apresentada uma resolução que se adapte independente do tipo de estrutura. Leonorris, se eu definir acho que não faz diferença definir a max-width, se eu definir width 100% por exemplo, mesmo assim chegará uma hora em que o menu será quebrado.